# Shopping basket subtotal

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, shopping-cart

hoping someone can help me with this! got a simple order list but if someone clicks an option, but then changes their mind and clicks a different option, it just keeps adding the values together... not sure how to solve it... code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    total = 0;
    function Update_Subtotal(radio){
        price = radio.getAttribute("price");
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(price);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = '£' + total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 1</legend> 
        <input type="radio" price="100" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Sub1
        <input type="radio" price="200" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Sub2
        <input type="radio" price="300" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Sub3
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 2</legend> 
        <input type="radio" price="10" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Sub1
        <input type="radio" price="20" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Sub2
        <input type="radio" price="30" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Sub3
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="total"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now lets sell in Option 1 I select sub2 then in Option 2 I select sub 1... The total I get is 210 which is correct, but then, if I change my mind and in Option 2 I select sub 3, the answer I should have is 230, but the total I get is 240

Thanks in advance for your help!

James

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect whether the radio has been checked or unchecked, and subtract if it's been unchecked, try changing:

```
total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(price);
```

to

```
if(radio.checked){
    total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(price);
}
else{
    total = parseInt(total) - parseInt(price);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you need to do at least these two things:

- Change `price` to `value`
- Add radio group names

There may be other things you would want to do, but here's a fairly simple port of your code doing those two.  Note that it no longer requires that you pass the actual radio button into the function.  It recalculates every time.  This means that you could probably do a better job attaching the event listener at a higher level too and not have to do the explicit event listener attachment in the markup.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    total = 0;
    function Update_Subtotal() {
        var inputs = document.forms.form.elements, total = 0;;
        for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
            var input = inputs[i];
            if (input.checked) {
                total += parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = '£' + total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 1</legend> 
        <input name="opt1" type="radio" value="100" onclick="Update_Subtotal();" />Sub1
        <input name="opt1" type="radio" value="200" onclick="Update_Subtotal();" />Sub2
        <input name="opt1" type="radio" value="300" onclick="Update_Subtotal();" />Sub3
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 2</legend> 
        <input name="opt2" type="radio" value="10" onclick="Update_Subtotal();" />Sub1
        <input name="opt2" type="radio" value="20" onclick="Update_Subtotal();" />Sub2
        <input name="opt2" type="radio" value="30" onclick="Update_Subtotal();" />Sub3
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="total"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works really well, as it is, but My code is a little simplified when posted about. I already have name attb added but Im using the value attb already for when i pass the form to a php script. Any way to do this with my original price attb? I understan it wont validate, but im not worried about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing your mind in this case means first undoing the choice you made and then making another one. Undoing the first choice means subtracting the amount that was added when you made that choice. Nowhere do you subtract, ever.

What you want to do is find a way to remember what the first choice was. One variable per fieldset is enough for that purpose.